# Let participants confirm registration with one click?

Tags: civievent, email, registration, confirmation

We frequently have trouble with participants not finishing the confirmation process (after being allowed to participate --> pending from approval), because offering them all data input fields again is confusing them.

So I'd like to make the link sent within the "Please confirm your registration" mail directly confirm the registration without having to go through all registration pages again (directly link to the Thank you-page).

Is that possible? (Very limited php/html skills available...)

Thank you in advance!

Drupal 7.43 with CiviCRM 4.6.4

Comment: which CMS do you have?

Comment: I'm sorry, we are on Drupal 7.43 with CiviCRM 4.6.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that would be:

Create a drupal webform where you show the CiviCRM user and the Event and a Submit button that registrates the visitor to the Event.

If you use a checksum token in the link then the person you mail will be shown on that page.

With a second parameter in the URL, for example "&action=register", you can use Javascript to auto-submit that form.

(Simirarly you can also create a cancel webform + email to send to people who already registered, so you make it easy for them to let you know that they will not be there).